# connection between apache camel and optaplanner

Tags: java, apache-camel, optaplanner

I have used optaplanner in my grails application,then i came to know about apache camel.

I have no idea about apache camel.

What is the relation between apache camel and optaplanner and is it necessary/good to use apache camel while using optaplannner for problem solving.

Answer (score 2):

Using Camel is of course by no means necessary in order to use Optaplanner. These tools occupy entirely different problem domains--Camel is a routing engine, and Optaplanner is a planning engine.

Camel is useful for routing messages from a variety of sources, say, Soap and Rest services, JMS, etc. to other endpoints or processors.

Camel does have a [component](http://camel.apache.org/optaplanner.html) for routing to Optaplanner. This could be useful if, say, you have planning problems that you receive via a queue or a webservice; Camel could receive the problem, route it to Optaplanner to solve, and return the solution.